# Cycling through a dictionary of dataframes for values above a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to set up a way to cycle though a 100 element dictionary, where each element is a 42,000 row dataframe and check whether the value is above a threshold

I am having problems working out how to store the row data so it is not overwritten.
I've made a simple example of what I would like to do:

I have a three element dictionary (my_dic) where each element is a dataframe 
I want to cycle through each row of every dataframe and check if any of the columns are above a threshold number.
I have been trying to use .any() and .where but I dont know how to capture the data for each df separately.

I would like to end up with three separate new df that have boolean values in each column that is above the threshold.

Any help would be great!

```
d1 = np.random.rand(3,3)
d2 = np.random.rand(3,3)
d3 = np.random.rand(3,3)

df1 =pd.DataFrame(d1, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 =pd.DataFrame(d2, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df3 =pd.DataFrame(d3, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

my_dic = {}
my_dic['a'] = df1   
my_dic['b'] = df2  
my_dic['c'] = df3   

threshold = 0.5
```

I want to cycle through every row of each of the keys in my_dic and change the value to booleans if it is greater than a threshold number

```
for k in my_dic:
    print k
    data = my_dic[k]
    for row in range(len(data)):
        print row
        np.where(data.iloc[row,:] > threshold)
```

This is the point I am struggling with, Im not sure how to keep this data, without it being overwritten

Comment: Please don't shout in your posts.

Comment: Also, if you have a column with no elements above the threshold, does it get displayed still?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I was shouting.  How do I know if I am shouting?

Comment: The # next to a sentence bloats the sentence as a header.

Comment: Yes, if there are no elements in a columns above the threshold, I would like it to be displayed as false or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for a *dict comprhension*, if you just want a boolean mask.

```
result = {k : v > threshold for k, v in my_dic.items()}
for v in result.values():
    print(v, '\n')

       0      1      2
a  False  False  False
b   True  False   True
c  False   True   True 

       0     1     2
a  False  True  True
b   True  True  True
c  False  True  True 

       0      1      2
a  False  False  False
b  False  False  False
c   True   True  False
```

If you want the result as `0/1`, use `astype`:

```
result = {k : v.gt(threshold).astype(int) for k, v in my_dic.items()}
```